# How to get source code location information of node with Cheerio?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I'm trying to get the source code location of node.

There is parse5 (use by [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio)) [sourceCodeLocationInfo](https://github.com/inikulin/parse5/blob/master/packages/parse5/docs/options/parser-options.md#optional-sourcecodelocationinfo) option.
But with this test code :

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const $ = cheerio.load('<html><head><title>Test page</title></head><body></body></html>', { sourceCodeLocationInfo: true })
let title = $('title');

console.log(title.text());
console.log(title.sourceCodeLocation);
```

`sourceCodeLocation` property of `title` is `undefined`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the Cheerio version on NPM is not up to date.

Version 1.0.0-rc.3 is available and not version 1.0.0.

From GitHub, I installed version 1.0.0 this way `npm install https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio.git#v1.0.0`. Everything is OK.

Comment: It has been almost a year... seems like 1.0.0-rc.3 is still the latest on NPM :(